# javascript doing multiple createrange() while encountering unexpected anchorOffset

Tags: javascript

My goal:

> Let users highlight different substring in a single long string.

However, once I've highlighted one substring with `range.surroundContents(newNode)` (newNode is a `span` with yellow background), the `innerHTML` of the whole long string changed-- it started to contain the `span` element; consequently, if the user wants to highlight a substring after the previous highlighted substring in the same long string, the `anchorOffset` will return the index starting `after` the previous span.

For example, in this long string:

> "Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much."

this long sentence is wrapped by a `p` whose class name is `noting`. If the `range.surroundContents()` method the substring "Privet Drive", then, when I want to get the `window.getSelection().anchorOffset` of the substring "thank", the answer wrongly is **53** while the correct answer should be **102**.
How should I do? Thank you!!

P.S. I don't want to use substring method to find the position, thank you!

```
$(".noting").mouseup(function(e){            
    $("#noteContent").val("");/*flushing*/
    curSentNum = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    $('#curSentNum').val(curSentNum);
    highlightLangName = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[2];
    $('#highlightLangName').val(highlightLangName);
    //console.log(".noting $(this).html()"+$(this).html()+" "+$(this).attr("id"));//id, for example: p-2-French
    if (window.getSelection) {
        highlightedText = window.getSelection().toString();
        curAnchorOffset = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;

        $('#anchorAt').val(curAnchorOffset);
        $('#highlightLen').val(highlightedText.length);

    }
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        highlightedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

});
```

And then I'll save the `anchorAt` information to db; after the db operation, I'll immediately call this function using the previous variables remained:

```
function highlightNoteJustSaved(){
    var curI = noteCounter;
    var anchorAt = parseInt($("#anchorAt").val());
    var highlightLen = parseInt($("#highlightLen").val());
    /*p to find, for example: p-2-French*/
    var curP = document.getElementById('p-'+curSentNum.toString()+"-"+$("#highlightLangName").val());
    var range = document.createRange();
    root_node = curP;

    range.setStart(root_node.childNodes[0], anchorAt);
    range.setEnd(root_node.childNodes[0], anchorAt+highlightLen);

    var newNode = document.createElement("span");
    newNode.style.cssText="background-color:#ceff99";//yellow
    newNode.className = alreadyNoteStr;
    newNode.setAttribute('id','already-note-'+curI.toString());

    range.surroundContents(newNode);
}
```

for HTML tree node structure, please take a look at the comment below( I didn't figure out how to copy-paste the code at this asking area).

Comment: Thank you  very much. I have added some verifiable example.

Comment: @Cindy I think you need to add your HTML structure also to understand what really is going on.

Comment: @Teocci, the stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to add my html code. so I put the code here: <div id="div-0" class="only-left-border"><p class="lan-English noting" id="p-1-English">Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much.</p><p class="only-left-border-pink noting lan-Chinese" id="p-1-Chinese">家住水蠟樹街四號的德思禮夫婦總是得意地說他們是非常規矩的人家。拜託，拜託了。</p></div>

Comment: After highlighting the first substring, the whole innerhtml becomes like this:
<div id="div-0" class="only-left-border">
<p class="lan-English noting" id="p-1-English">Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, <span class="already-note" id="already-note-0" style="background-color: rgb(206, 255, 153);">Privet Drive</span>, were proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much.</p><p class="only-left-border-pink noting lan-Chinese" id="p-1-Chinese">家住水蠟樹街四號的德思禮夫婦總是得意地說他們是非常規矩的人家。拜託，拜託了。</p></div>

Comment: So to make it more clear, your problem is that you want to have the selection offset from the original text, but after having created your highlighting node, the selection is based on the modified tree, is that right? Why don't you want to use substring exactly? Walking over the selected nodes and getting their textContent would be a way. An other would be to use a less intrusive highlighting method, e.g absolutely positioned elements behind the text (this is what code-mirror does)

Comment: The reason is because a sentence may contain multiple duplicate words but I only want  to show the exact word the user initially selected( though this is a stupid reason :DD ). So I could do research on code-mirror?(I haven't heard of this before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced your method to highlight text with 2 methods. `highlightTextNodes` finds the word in the content of the node. Searching each child. Also I implemented a highlight remover to show how it works. I replaced the `span` with a `mark` tag.

```js
let alreadyNoteStr = 'already';
let noteCounter = 0;
let elementId;

$('p.noting').mouseup(function(e) {
  elementId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#noteContent').val(''); /*flushing*/
  curSentNum = elementId.split('-')[1];
  $('#curSentNum').val(curSentNum);
  highlightLangName = elementId.split('-')[2];
  $('#highlightLangName').val(highlightLangName);
  //console.log(".noting $(this).html()"+$(this).html()+" "+$(this).attr("id"));//id, for example: p-2-French
  if (window.getSelection) {
    highlightedText = window.getSelection().toString();
    curAnchorOffset = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;

    $("#noteContent").val(highlightedText);
    $('#anchorAt').val(curAnchorOffset);
    $('#highlightLen').val(highlightedText.length);

    highlight(elementId, highlightedText);
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    highlightedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
});

function highlightNoteJustSaved() {
  let curI = noteCounter;
  let anchorAt = parseInt($("#anchorAt").val());
  let highlightLen = parseInt($("#highlightLen").val());
  /*p to find, for example: p-2-French*/
  let curP = document.getElementById('p-' + curSentNum.toString() + "-" + $("#highlightLangName").val());
  let range = document.createRange();
  rootNode = curP;
  let childNode = rootNode.childNodes[0];

  range.setStart(rootNode.childNodes[0], anchorAt);
  range.setEnd(rootNode.childNodes[0], anchorAt + highlightLen);

  var newNode = document.createElement("span");
  newNode.style.cssText = "background-color:#ceff99"; //yellow
  newNode.className = alreadyNoteStr;
  newNode.setAttribute('id', 'already-note-' + curI.toString());

  range.surroundContents(newNode);
}

/*
 * Takes in an array of consecutive TextNodes and returns a document fragment with `word` highlighted
 */
function highlightTextNodes(nodes, word) {
  if (!nodes.length) {
    return;
  }

  let text = '';

  // Concatenate the consecutive nodes to get the actual text
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    text += nodes[i].textContent;
  }

  let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  while (true) {
    // Tweak this if you want to change the highlighting behavior
    var index = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase());

    if (index === -1) {
      break;
    }

    // Split the text into [before, match, after]
    var before = text.slice(0, index);
    var match = text.slice(index, index + word.length);
    text = text.slice(index + word.length);

    // Create the <mark>
    let mark = document.createElement('mark');
    mark.className = 'found';
    mark.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match));

    // Append it to the fragment
    fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(before));
    fragment.appendChild(mark);
  }

  // If we have leftover text, just append it to the end
  if (text.length) {
    fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  }

  // Replace the nodes with the fragment
  nodes[0].parentNode.insertBefore(fragment, nodes[0]);

  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    let node = nodes[nodes.length - i - 1];
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}


/*
 * Highlights all instances of `word` in `$node` and its children
 */
function highlight(id, word) {
  let node = document.getElementById(id);
  let children = node.childNodes;
  let currentRun = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    let child = children[i];

    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      // Keep track of consecutive text nodes
      currentRun.push(child);
    } else {
      // If we hit a regular element, highlight what we have and start over
      highlightTextNodes(currentRun, word);
      currentRun = [];

      // Ignore text inside of our <mark>s
      if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && child.className !== 'found') {
        highlight(child, word);
      }
    }
  }

  // Just in case we have only text nodes as children
  if (currentRun.length) {
    highlightTextNodes(currentRun, word);
  }
}

/*
 * Removes all highlighted <mark>s from the given node
 */
function unhighlight(id) {
  let node = document.getElementById(id);
  let marks = [].slice.call(node.querySelectorAll('mark.found'));

  for (var i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
    let mark = marks[i];

    // Replace each <mark> with just a text node of its contents
    mark.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(mark.childNodes[0].textContent), mark);
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

label>span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="unhighlight(elementId);">Unhighlight</button>
<div id="div-0" class="only-left-border">
  <p class="lan-English noting" id="p-1-English">Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much.</p>
</div>

<label><span>Content:</span><input type="text" id="noteContent"></input></label>
<label><span>Numer:</span><input type="text" id="curSentNum"></input></label>
<label><span>Language:</span><input type="text" id="highlightLangName"></input></label>
<label><span>Anchor:</span><input type="text" id="anchorAt"></input></label>
<label><span>Length:</span><input type="text" id="highlightLen"></input></label>
```